Vb.net SendKeys
I have the following code meant to just send keys from keyboard to any application open in windows, using generic string "aaa".
Imports Windows.VisualBasic
Devices.Keyboard.SendKeys("aaa")
It does not let me run the code, it gives the error BC30469: Referente to a non-shared member requires a object referente.
Thanks in advance for the help.
Tried the code above.
